# Why do I not get redirected to another page and how do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, redirect

I currently have this JS code that gets inputted information in a form and saves it to the local storage. This works but I needed to add e.preventDefault(); to prevent the page from reloading before my code was executed.

I added window.location.href="filtered-buildings" but it is currently not working.

Here is the source code:

```
window.addEventListener('load', init);

let listString = ["slope", "wheelchairLift", "buildingLift", "disabledBathroom","wheelchairAcs", "automaticDoors", "manualDoors"];
let filterForm;


function init () {
    filterForm = document.getElementById('filter-form');
    filterForm.addEventListener('submit', setFormInput);

}

function setFormInput (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    for (let i = 0; i <= listString.length; i++) {
        localStorage.setItem(listString[i], document.getElementById(listString[i]).checked);
    }

    window.location.href="filtered-buildings.php";
}
```

I have tried changing the window variable but this did not work. I am unsure on how to fix this propperly, but I am 95% sure the window load event is making the line mess up. How would I propperly fix this?

Comment: _"but I am 95% sure the window load event is making the line mess up"_ - why, what should that have to do with this?

Comment: As I said I'm not sure. Might also just be the prevent default but then I'd need to know how to prevent it from refreshing before it can save the information

Comment: You should omit window. Just do `location.href = "your_url"`

Comment: You are most likely getting a JavaScript error (did you not check the console?), because your loop is iterating too far. `listString.length` is 7, and you make your loop iterate from 0 to 7. That's _eight_ iterations.

Comment: So the last "value" you will be accessing from your list is `undefined`, and `document.getElementById(undefined).checked` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: just putting location.href = "filtered-buildings" does not work

Comment: Oh yeah it was literally just <=. Changed it to < and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the action of the form to 'filtered-buildings.php'?

That way you don't have to do the `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: so as stupid as this sounds, I am doing this for a school project and I need to add events. e.preventDefault is technically an event, so I am literally just doing this so I can get a higher grade.

Comment: I got it though, but thanks for the input anyways